# How to find height of an element which is loading by Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, selector

I want to resize the height of one element in html to have equal height with another element so I am trying to get the height of element by its class in my HTML which is loading by Ajax , I used jQuery like

```
if($('someclass').lenght) {
  var newheight = $('myclass').height(); 
  $('someclass').height(newheight)
}
```

But it gives me zero height I am assuming maybe I need to use timeout or is there any other way to get the proper height because when I inspect the element it shows the height and it is not zero.
Thanks

Comment: Do you know your code is running after the AJAX completes? Please show your actual code if possible.

Comment: You need to use relevant ajax callback once element's content is added to the DOM.

Comment: can you please put your ajax code here

Comment: try `$(".myClass").css("height")`... maybe you will need to set the height in a setTimeout in order to give some time for the browser to recompute the element state after you change it at the end of a ajax request... it is a trick...

Comment: It is a Jason code and sorry for now I can't provide the code , could you please post some example how to use callback. Thanks

Comment: Seeing your JSON isn't as helpful as seeing how your AJAX call is implemented, and more importantly, whether or not the above code snippet is running AFTER the call completes.

Comment: There are many reasons for your height to return 0, we need more information from you in order to diagnose why yours is returning 0.  Please just post the ajax call as everyone is requesting or we can't help you

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert the HTML to your DOM before trying to get it's height. See [jQuery API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/) what function you can use to manipulate DOM. For example [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or [after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/).

Then, you'll probably want to use [`outerHeight()`](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) to get height of the element including border and margins.